# How do I get user id, from JWT or request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

In my Spring Boot application (let's say it is blog app) I am using JWT authentication.

If I want to create a new post, should I pass the user ID inside the request body? But is it insecure to do so. Because, I should store user id in localstorage in front-end and put it in request before sending.
Or I should get user id from JWT? But, I have to inject that authManager dependency in all my controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should get the `userId` from the JWT token.
The token should be added on **all** requests and must be validated before the backend do any action.

And you don't have to add the `AuthManager` to all of your controllers. You can setup rules with Spring-Security. Have a look at this: https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/

At the end: You can inject the AuthManager only at places where you need the username. Or let Spring add the Authentication.

```java
public class YourController {

   @POST
   public void create(@RequestBody Post post, Authentication auth) {
      // from the auth you can extract the users name or id
   }
}
```